# Is there configuration validation tool available?

Tags: validation, chef-infra, puppet, staf

There are tools like chef/puppet are there for configuration management. we can mention the resource and the tool will make sure whether it is present or absent.

This simplifies lot of things. But what i look for configuration validation. Chef and puppet either install or uninstall the configuration rather than just validate. Is there any tool which will say the configuration exists or not by validating it?

Comment: I feel fairly certain this is a duplicate because I saw a good detailed answer to it before with multiple options and pros/cons, but the short answer is http://serverspec.org/ I don't recall where the good answer was.

Comment: Check out test kitchen that supports both serverspec. inspec and chefspec (if you're using chef). Test kitchen was originally developed for chef but supports all CM languages now via plugins.

Comment: As @MarkO'Connor mentions, there are some cool tools built around serverspec for these purposes. Another is infrataster. You can also build your own, like RIPieenar did with Serverspec+Docker+Sensu for continuous application validation and monitoring.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard I never heard of serverspec and i tried it today . such a nice tool. Though you have downvoted still your small answer is big + for me. Thanks

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I didn't downvote you. Why would you think that I would downvote you after I left two comments? If you want to see some cool advanced tricks, check this blog article here: https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-serverspec-test-infrastructure.html or some of my snippets here: https://github.com/mschuchard/snippets-and-notes/tree/master/serverspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InSpec and Serverspec are, as mentioned, built explicitly for this. Chef's why-run and Puppet's dry-run modes can also help by showing what would be changed if they were run.